# how to add node in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

how to add new node in xslt in each node .here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFw/4
**Input**

```
<test>
    <video graph="1" potime="1811">
        <sec>
            <secid>3812907</secid>
            <pick>
                <vdsecname>A</vdsecname>
                <mediadate>24 Apr 2017, 7:45PM IST</mediadate>
                <v>240420171945</v>

            </pick>
            <pick>
                <vdsecname>D</vdsecname>
                <mediadate>20 Apr 2017, 4:30PM IST</mediadate>
                <v>200420171630</v>
            </pick>
            <pick>
                <vdsecname>E</vdsecname>
                <mediadate>20 Apr 2017, 3:30PM IST</mediadate>
                 <v>200420171530</v>
            </pick>

        </sec>
    </video>
    <video graph="1" potime="94">
        <sec>
            <secid>20970242</secid>
            <pick>
                <vdsecname>B</vdsecname>
                <mediadate>23 Apr 2017, 7:30PM IST</mediadate>
                 <v>230420171930</v>
            </pick>
            <pick>
                <vdsecname>C</vdsecname>
                <mediadate>22 Apr 2017, 5:33PM IST</mediadate>
                 <v>220420171733</v>
            </pick>
        </sec>
    </video>
</test>
```

**output**

```
<videos>
        <pick>

            <vdsecname>A</vdsecname>

            <mediadate>24 Apr 2017, 7:45PM IST</mediadate>

            <v>240420171945</v>

            <domain>ddd</domain>
        </pick>
        <pick>

            <vdsecname>D</vdsecname>

            <mediadate>20 Apr 2017, 4:30PM IST</mediadate>

            <v>200420171630</v>
            <domain>ddd</domain>
        </pick>
        <pick>

            <vdsecname>E</vdsecname>

            <mediadate>20 Apr 2017, 3:30PM IST</mediadate>

            <v>200420171530</v>
            <domain>ddd</domain>
        </pick>

        <pick>

            <vdsecname>B</vdsecname>

            <mediadate>23 Apr 2017, 7:30PM IST</mediadate>

            <v>230420171930</v>
            <domain>ddd</domain>
        </pick>
        <pick>

            <vdsecname>C</vdsecname>

            <mediadate>22 Apr 2017, 5:33PM IST</mediadate>

            <v>220420171733</v>
            <domain>ddd</domain>
        </pick>

    </videos>
```

I do like this

```
  <xsl:variable
name="variableA">
<videos>

<xsl:for-each select="test/video">
    <xsl:copy-of select="sec/pick"/>
    <domain>ddd</domain>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </videos>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$variableA"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work. The first template matches the root element, adds a `<videos>` element and applies templates to all the `pick` elements. The second template matches a `pick` element, copies it and its contents, and adds the `domain` element.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <videos>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="video/sec/pick" />
        </videos>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pick">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()" />
            <domain>ddd</domain>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFw/6

Comment: see it is not correct solution ..:( see my expected output

Comment: first check this http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFw/4 .I merge my all `pick` tag in variable inside `videos` tag

Comment: @user944513 Ok, I now see that your output isn't just a copy of the input with the extra elements added (you failed to mention that). Your xsltransform.net example also has a bunch of HTML stuff (although it is misspelled as `hmtl`. Do you want that too? Your question doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: wait I will explain again .see first this http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFw/4 my output .in that see `vdsecname` tag it start from `ADEBC` ..all pick tag is inside the `videos ` tag

Comment: @user944513 Ok, I see that now. But you haven't answered my question about the HTML stuff.

Comment: no I don't want html anything.I just want my `$variableA` in each `pick` tag I need to add `domain`  tag

Comment: did you get my point ? I need to update my $variableA .In each pick tag I need to add `domain` node